# Uniqueness of elementary measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If we define finite union of boxes as elementary sets. Then define a measure of these sets as follows:

Let $E \subset \mathbf{R}^d$,If $E$ is partitioned as the finite union $B_1 \cup  \cdots \cup B_k$ of disjoint boxes. then $$m(E):= |B_1| + \cdots +|B_k|$$

Let $m'  : \varepsilon(\mathbf{R}^d) \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^+$ be a map from the collection of $\varepsilon(\mathbf{R}^d)$ of elementary subsets of $\mathbf{R}^d$ to the nonnegative reals that obeys the non-negativity, finite additivity, and translation invariance properties. then there exists a constant $c \in \mathbf{R}^+$,such that $m'(E)=cm(E)$ for all elementary sets $E$.

---

Because any elementary sets can be expressed as the finite union of disjoint boxes, so we only need to prove it is true for boxes. Set $c=m'([0,1)^d)$, by finite additivity and translation invariance, we get $m'([0,1)^d)=n^d\times m'([0,\frac{1}{n})^d)$,then $m'([0,\frac{1}{n})^d)=c\frac{1}{n^d}$,clearly, for any $r \in \mathbf{Q}$, we have $m'([0,r)^d)=c r^d$. But if $t$ is an irrational number, I don't know how to get $m'([0,t)^d)=ct^d$. It's unclear whether this method would solve this problem. Please help me. thanks.

Comment: Use finite additivity and non-negativity to show that if $E\subset F$, then $m'(E) \leq m'(F)$. Then show that $m'([0,t)^d)\geq cr^d$ for every $r<t$, and $m'([0,t)^d)\leq cr^d$ for every $r>t$.

Comment: Even with this, how do we conclude the proof? When we consider an arbitrary elementary set, the boxes need not be of the form $\left[ 0, r \right)^d$. In general, they are Cartesian products of intervals.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that finite additivity implies that $t \mapsto m'([0,t)^d)$ is monotone increasing (Do you see how?). So for any rational $r,s$ with $r < t < s$ we have $cr^d \le m'([0,t)^d) \le cs^d$ and are done by denseness of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$.