# How $n^d \times m([0, \frac{1}{n}[^d) = m([0, 1[^d)$ follows from translation invariance and (finite) additivity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions

[In this StackExchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498369/uniqueness-of-elementary-measure) (which itself seems to reference to an exercise in Terence Tao's lecture notes on introductory measure theory on his blog [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/245a-prologue-the-problem-of-measure/)), it's said that assuming "finite additivity" (that is, $m(E_1 \cup \ldots \cup E_n) =m(E_1) + \dots + m(E_n)$ for finite number of disjoint sets $E_i$) and translation invariance (i.e. $m(E +x) = m(E)$) hold for function $m': \varepsilon(\mathbf{R}^d) \to \mathbf{R}^+$ ($\varepsilon(\mathbf{R}^d)$ being collection of elementary subsets of $\mathbf{R}^d)$, it can be shown that

$$n^d \times m'([0, \frac{1}{n}[^d) = m'([0, 1[^d).$$

I can't manage to see how. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that

$$
[0,1)^d = \biguplus_{k \in \{0, \dots, n-1\}^d} E_{k,n},
$$

where the symbol denotes a disjoint(!) union and the set $E_{k,n}$ is defined by

$$
E_{k,n} := \prod_{i=1}^d \left[\frac{k_i}{n}, \frac{k_i+1}{n} \right) = [0,1/n)^d + k.
$$

This especially implies that $\mu(E_{k,n}) = \mu([0,1/n)^d)$ by translation invariance.

Noting that the index-set $\{0, \dots, n-1\}^d$ in the above union has exactly $n^d$ elements completes the proof (why?).

Comment: ...because there are $n^d$ (a finite number) elements in the disjoint union $\bigcup_k E_{k,n} = [0,1)$, $m(E_{k,n})$ each, so because finite additivity, m([0,1)) = n^d m(E_{k,n}) (edit. okay, now the comment is complete; the enter key's functionality in the comment mode was surprising  >.>)

Comment: (or not: ought to be  "*$m(E_{k,n}) = m([0, 1/n)^d) $ each" in my previous comment.)

Comment: "$[0,1)=\cdots$" should be replaced with  "$[0,1)^d=\cdots$".