# Uniqueness of elementary measure, extending from cubes to boxes

Tags: measure-theory

In this question [Uniqueness of elementary measure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/498369/414731), the uniqueness of the elementary measure is proved for cubes of the form $[0,r)^{d}$, $r\in\mathbb{R}$. I am struggling to extend this to the general case of a box, where the intervals may be of different lengths.

Am I supposed to use the following?
$$m'\left(\prod_{i=1}^{d}(a_{i}, b_{i})\right) = \prod_{i=1}^{d}m'((a_i, b_i))$$
The exercise from Tao doesn't explictly state that the new measure $m'$ is defined this way (only that it obeys non-negativity, finite additivity, and translation invariance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 2 Dimensions

### Rational ratios

You can create any $1\times n$ box by stacking n $1$-cubes, and any $1/m\times 1$ box by stacking m $1/m$-cubes. So you can get any $1/m \times n$ box by stacking nm $1/m$-cubes.

So you can get any $q/m \times qn$ boxes stacking nm $q/m$-cubes.

Since we can find $q\in\mathbb{Q},m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that these equations hold

$$a=q/m, b=qn$$

for every rational a and b, we have it for all rational boxes.

### Real ratios

you can do something similar to the answer for the question you linked:

simply approximate a $1\times r$ box from below and above with rationals and then utilize the non-negativity of your measure and density of the rationals. Once you have any real length to height ratio, you can simply scale the entire argument to get the formula for any real box.

## n dimensions

You can let (n-1) have the same side length and show that you can have arbitrary side length ratios of the n'th dimension and the rest. (Same argument as above). Then use induction to obtain the remaining flexibility.